# SVG marker id can't be found

Tags: html, svg, marker

[image]

I have a web block list. This web block has divs each one with the code below which I display according to the sent Id.

These are the codes for each div:

## Div1

```
 <svg width='200' height='176'>
      <defs>
        <marker id='arrowThree' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
          <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowThree)' />
      <line x1='178' y1='160' x2='27' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowThree)' />
      <line x1='10' y1='20' x2='10' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowThree)' />
    </svg>
```

## Div2

```
  <svg width='200' height='118'>
      <defs>
        <marker id='arrowTwo' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
          <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowTwo)' /> 
      <line x1='182' y1='110' x2='27' y2='18' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowTwo)' />
      <line x1='10' y1='15' x2='10' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowTwo)' />
    </svg>
```

## DIV3

```
 <svg width='200' height='60' id='teste'>
      <defs id='teste1'>
        <marker id='arrowLeftDown' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
          <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <line x1='10' y1='5' x2='10' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrowLeftDown)' />
    </svg>
```

The list will always have (div1 or div2) and div3.

Eg:

Div1 Div1 Div3 Div3 Div3 Div3

Or

Div2 Div3 Div3 Div3

The problem is that div3 doesn't recognize the id "arrowLeftDown", but if I use "arrowThree" if it's after Div1 or "arrowTwo" if after Div2 it works and adds the marker. But I can't have this distinction once my list is dynamic and I don't want to create many Div3, one for each Div1 and Div2.

Comment: what you you mean Div3 Div3 Div3, you can't repeat Div3 if it contains an id as id values must be globally unique in a document.

Comment: As it is a list, I have DIV2 in the first item, DIV3 in the second item, DIV3, in the third item, etc. As you can see on the image attached.

But it is a web block and according to the id I send as input parameter I show either div1, div2 or div 3

Comment: Does div3 exist more than once in the document?

Comment: Yes, it does, in more than one item of the list. If you see the image, each arrow down is a div3

Comment: Well as I said in my first comment, you can't do that and have it work.

Comment: In the left list I have a div1 in the first item then a div3 in the second and third item. When i use  "marker-end='url(#arrowThree)'" (Same id as in the marker of div1), it works. But if I use "marker-end='url(#arrowLeftDown)'" it doesn't show the marker in the end of the line for the div3

Comment: I have it working on the left list...

Comment: @RobertLongson I believe my question would be more like "How can I use the same marker in all SVG tags?"

Comment: Have some common <defs> location where all markers are defined once only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a SVG tag with defs before the other divs like this:

```
<svg width='0' height='0'>
      <defs>
        <marker id='arrow' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='0' refY='3' orient='auto' markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
          <path d='M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z' fill='#000' />
        </marker>
      </defs>
</svg>

<div>
    <svg width='200' height='176'>
      <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
      <line x1='178' y1='160' x2='27' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
      <line x1='10' y1='20' x2='10' y2='140' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
    </svg>
</div>

<div>
    <svg width='200' height='118'>  
      <line x1='185' y1='5' x2='185' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' /> 
      <line x1='182' y1='110' x2='27' y2='18' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
      <line x1='10' y1='15' x2='10' y2='82' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
    </svg>
</div>

<div>
    <svg width='200' height='60'> 
      <line x1='10' y1='5' x2='10' y2='25' stroke='#000' stroke-width='3' marker-end='url(#arrow)' />
    </svg>
</div>
```